# DatePickerDialog showing abnormal behaviour in android 5.1 when timezone is changed

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I have to show calender using DatePickerDialog.

The below code is used:

```html
    import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
 
public class DatePickerExample extends Activity {
 
    private TextView Output;
    private Button changeDate;
 private Boolean mEnableNativeCalGridView = null; 
 String timeZone;
 public static TimeZone tz;
    private int year;
    private int month;
    DatePickerDialog d;
    public Calendar c;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    private int day;
    public static IntentFilter s_intentFilter;
 
    static final int DATE_PICKER_ID = 1111; 
    static{ 
        s_intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
        s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
        s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
    } 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        registerReceiver(m_timeChangedReceiver, s_intentFilter);  
        Output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Output);
        changeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeDate);
        
      //  sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, ''yy");//Wed, Jul 4, '01
        
        // Show current date
         
        Output.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
                .append(year).append(" "));
  
        // Button listener to show date picker dialog
         
        changeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 
                // On button click show datepicker dialog 
                showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID);
 
            }
 
        });
   }
   
    @Override 
    protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_PICKER_ID: 
            ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(
                c.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        } 
    } 
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_PICKER_ID:
             
            // open datepicker dialog. 
            // set date picker for current date 
            // add pickerListener listner to date picker
         sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
         tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
           System.out.println("TimeZone   "+tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT)+" Timezon id :: " +tz.getID());
           timeZone = tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);
         c= Calendar.getInstance();
         c.setTimeZone(tz);
            year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            
             d = new DatePickerDialog(DatePickerExample.this, pickerListener, year, month,day);
             setMinMaxdate();
             return d;
             
        }
        return null;
    }
    ////////////////////Fix for issue on OS 5.1 //////////////////////
    public long  getDateFormatted(String date){
    String givenDateString = date; 
    
    
    long timeInMilliseconds = 0;
    try { 
        Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
        timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
        System.out.println("Date in milli :: " + timeInMilliseconds);
    } catch (ParseException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    return timeInMilliseconds;
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////
   private DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener  newchange=  new OnDateChangedListener(){

      @Override
      public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, 
        int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
         "onDateChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       
      }};
      DatePicker datePicker;
    public void setMinMaxdate() {
        //Time zone calculation
     
       //TimeZone.setDefault(tz);
       /////////////////////// 
     long calEvtEndDate= getDateFormatted("Sun May 31 23:59:59 "+timeZone+" 2015");//System.currentTimeMillis();
     long calEvtStartDate= getDateFormatted("Wed May 13 00:00:00 "+timeZone+" 2015");//System.currentTimeMillis()/2;

    // long calEvtEndDate = getDateFormatted("Sun, may 31, '15");
     //long calEvtStartDate = getDateFormatted("Wed, may 13, '15");
     if(d != null){
     datePicker = d.getDatePicker();
     

     if(mEnableNativeCalGridView != null){
      
     datePicker.setCalendarViewShown(mEnableNativeCalGridView.booleanValue());
     }

             // If Start Date is Greater than End Date then we are showing from valid StartDate 
             // value and we are not setting the maxdate.
             if (calEvtStartDate > calEvtEndDate) {
                 datePicker.setMinDate(calEvtStartDate);
             } else {
                 if (calEvtStartDate > 0) { // If Only ValidStart date is provided, then setting the minDate.
                  
                  datePicker.setMinDate(calEvtStartDate);
                  
                    
                 }
                 if (calEvtEndDate > 0) { // If Only ValidEnd date is provided, then setting the maxDate.
                  
                     datePicker.setMaxDate(calEvtEndDate);
                     
                 }
             }
         }
     
     }
    

 
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onResume();
     System.out.println("-------resumed");
     
     
     
    }
    
    
    public DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
 

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
         //view.updateDate(year, month, day);
         System.out.println("---------------datesetchange");
            year  = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day   = selectedDay;
 
            // Show selected date 
            Output.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                    .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                    .append(" "));
     
           }
        };
        public void onDestroy() { 
            super.onDestroy(); 
            unregisterReceiver(m_timeChangedReceiver);     
        }  
        
        private final BroadcastReceiver m_timeChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                final String action = intent.getAction();
                
                if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED) ||
                    action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED))
                {  
                   System.out.println("timezone changed---"+action.toString());
                   tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
                  System.out.println("TimeZone   "+tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT)+" Timezon id :: " +tz.getID());
                  timeZone = tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);
//                  Intent intent1 = getIntent();
//                    finish();
//                    startActivity(intent1);
                
                  showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID);
                  
                }
    
   } 
        }; 
        
}
```

When the app is running, I go to the settings and change the Timezone to such a value so that the current date will change. Now when we select any date in the dialog, it behaves abnormally and goes to other date. I have used setMinDate() and setMaxDate() methods. This happens only in Android OS 5.1. 
Any idea or help? Thanks in advance.